# .bat file to rename and move files with prompt

Tags: batch-file

I am completely new to this, but I am trying to create a *`.bat`* file that will allow me to rename a pair of files within a designated folder and move them into a subfolder. The part I am having trouble with is that I am wanting a prompt to come up to identify/select the files to be renamed and moved.

Example file names are:

```
A1234, A1235, A1236, B1234, B1235, B1236, etc.
```

Is there a way to bring up a prompt that allows the user to type the shared name (ex 1234)of the files and rename and move both files to the designated subfolder?

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think for that you could use a search command to search with a patter "?1234" and then do a rename inside a loop iterated on the results found. Note that the `?` inside the string is a wildcard.

Comment: @MukulGoel can you give me a little more clarification on that? That's well past what I know how to do. I'll admit, I thought this was going to be much, much simpler than it's turned out to be...

Answer (score 1):

Suggested approach

for part of problem

> `part I am having trouble with is that I am wanting a prompt to come
>   up to identify/select the files to be renamed and moved. Is there a
>   way to bring up a prompt that allows the user to type the shared name
>   (ex 1234)of the files and rename and move both files to the designated
>   subfolder?`

Do a search operation using `wildcard`, like `"?1234"` for the case highlighted above ( should be made generalized for all acceptable and expected patterns `"*1234*"` is the generic most )

Now do a `RENAME` inside a `For` loop on the results obtained by search.

As you suggest you are a newbie with Batch, following tutorials will help you build your file. Look for elements like `Variables`, `For Loop`

[Batch Tutorial](https://cs.senecac.on.ca/~albert.pang/ios100/dosbatch.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
@echo off
set /p file=Please type shared name: 
for %%a in (C:\Folder\?%file%.*) do (
move "%%a" subdir
ren "subdir\%%a" newname.*
)
```